# Cake PHP Validation

Tags: cakephp

I'm just wondering if anyone can tell me how to validate two addresses (invice / billing) on the same form.

Obviously both the addresses represent one instance of the Address Model. I only want to submit one form though.

How can I validate each address individually, and how can I pass any errors retuned to the address that is being validated. As currently any errors are being passed to both forms.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you read this: http://book.cakephp.org/view/125/data-validation ?  Sorry to be rude if you have, but it's a start.